# Товары WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Собственно как выводить товары? Про woocommercy -> settings -> products -> shop page знаю
Мне нужно допустим выводить пару штук из последних товаров на главной странице или категории где то отдельно на другой странице и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// параметры по умолчанию
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'order'       => 'DESC',
) );

foreach( $posts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </a>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php

}

wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс


?>
```

или с шорткодом

```
[products limit = "5" columns = "5"]
```